# Not import all records to database

Tags: mysql, xampp

I try to import sql file that has about 70 MB so when I use command source in

```
xampp->mysql->bin
```

not all the records in the sql file imported
do you have idea about this problem ?

Comment: "I did something, and then something didn't happen" needs a lot more technical detail.

Comment: so what should I add to post ? I just do this and when check the table records I saw some records not exist so I can not show them in the post

Comment: You need to dig deeper. Is there a pattern? Did it import all tables, or skip a bunch? Often if an import fails you'll see that some tables are missing because it stopped at a certain point. Does that dump have the records or not?

Comment: actually all functions run without any problem when use source command and when I import the data no error were happen but when I want to use entities I cant find all records in tables

Comment: You're going to have to do a lot more research here. What records are missing? What pattern is there to the gaps? Do these records have something in common or not?